# ASP.Net Core project cannot find its Javascript files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am working through ["The Little ASP.Net Core Book"](https://recaffeinate.co/book/) using Visual Studio 2019 and Win10.  The project is set to build for w64.  I build it in debug mode to an executable file and run the file from a command window.  I am not running it using the "dotnet" command.

I have gotten through the point where my program is using my database to populate a screen, and I can use the screen to add new items to my database. Each item is displayed in its own little form, with its name and a checkbox. Rather than have a "submit" button for each item in the database, which would be really clunky, the next step in the project is to give each checkbox an event handler. Here's the Javascript file I am supposed to be using. It's named site.js, and it's in the wwwroot/js in my project.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Wire up all of the checkboxes to run markComnpleted()
    alert("Document ready function");
    $('.done-checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
        markCompleted(e.target);
    });
});

function markCompleted(checkbox) {
    alert("Mark completed function.");
    checkbox.disabled = true;
    var row = checkbox.closest('tr');
    $(row).addClass('done');
    var form = checkbox.closest('form');
    form.submit();
}
```

I added the alert calls so that I could see that this script is actually being executed. The "Document ready function" message should appear when the web page is first generated, and the "Mark completed function" should appear when I click a checkbox. Neither message is happening. I'm guessing that I missed a step (or the tutorial missed a step) that tells the web page to use this script. Here's the Index.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

@model ToDoViewModel
@using Humanizer 

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Manage your ToDo list";
}

<div class="panel panel-default todo-panel">
    <div class="panel-heading"> @ViewData["Title"]</div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>&#x2714;</td>
                <td>Item</td>
                <td>Due</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form asp-action="MarkDone" method="post">
                        <Input type="checkbox" class="done-checkbox" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.Id" />
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>@item.Title</td>
                <td>@item.DueAt.Humanize()</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <div class="panel-footer add-item-form">
        @await Html.PartialAsync("AddItemPartial", new ToDoItem()) 
    </div>
</div>
```

My layout file specifies the file at the end, after defining the footer for the page.  Here are the relevant lines:

```
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/site.js"></script>
```

My layout file, shared/_layout.cshtml, ends with this:

```
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

When I run my program and try to use it using https://localhost:5001/todo and pull up DevTools, it shows me that all attempts by my program to find Javascript files resulted in 404 (not found) errors.  When I hover my mouse over the name site.js on the DevTools network tab, the tooltip shows me the full file name 
s https://localhost:5001/js/site.js.

A helpful person on Reddit said that all of this looks correct.  Why isn't it working?  What more do you need me to show you?

After I posted the above, I tried it in Microsoft Edge.  DevTools from there told me that I had a second DOCTYPE line.  The page source showed me this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Manage your ToDo list - AspNetCoreTodo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AspNetCoreTodo</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Home/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="/ToDo">My ToDos</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <!DOCTYPE html>
```

My _layout.cshtml file has this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - AspNetCoreTodo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">AspNetCoreTodo</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="ToDo" asp-action="index">My ToDos</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
```

So, it looks like that call to RenderBody() is not working.  I do not see a definition of that method in my project.  Is it something I need to write myself, or should it be automatically generated?

I was asked to provide the csproj file.  Here it is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Humanizer" Version="2.7.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Views\ToDo\AddItemPartial.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>



</Project>
```

Comment: I suppose that you have this jquery code inside the @Scripts section of your page right?

Comment: Sorry I mean the $(document).ready() function

Comment: "I build it in debug mode to an executable file" - is it a single-executable file ? Can you update you question with the file structure or your executable?

Comment: I do not know what the @Scripts section of my page is.  This is my very first attempt at ASP.Net, and I don't yet really know what I'm doing.

Comment: I built it into an executable file named AspNetCoreTodo.exe.  I don't know how to provide the file structure you are asking me for.  I tried running the dll using "dotnet aspnetcoretoto.dll" and got the same result.

Comment: Can you update your question with the *.csproj file

Comment: @FrankNielsen Done

Comment: Remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` in `Index.cshtml`, it is already in your `_layout.cshtml` file

Comment: I already did that.  It didn't help.